# PHP S3 download: echo huge text variable to browser with header to download

Tags: php, csv, amazon-s3, text, echo

PHP S3 download: echo huge text variable to browser with header to download, but the page is getting timeout and not responding.

Here is my code to download a huge CSV file data from S3 services:

```
$result = $s3->getObject($_REQUEST['bucket'], $_REQUEST['path'], false);

if($result){
    header('Content-type: ' . $result->headers['type']);
    header('Content-Length: ' . $result->headers['size']);
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$_REQUEST['filename'].'"');

   echo $result->body;
} else {
    echo 'File not found';
}
```

I have also increased page execution time:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M' );
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Comment: also could follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-stream-wrapper.html i.e register the stream handler, then pipe it to the browser in chunks vs loading all in a PHP var then outputting once

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternate solution to above problem, instead of getting contents from aws and then buffering large amount of data to browser, i created "Public" url from the file and redirect user to the link.

```
// Getting the URL to an object
$url = $s3->getObjectUrl($targetBucket, $keyname);
// redirect user to the download link
header('Location: '.$url); exit;
```

If "Private" bucket and files, we can create a temporary bucket and copy the file to that bucket on request, like something below, and then again create link like above.

```
// temporary bucket for public files
$sourcebucket = '........';
$targetBucket = '........';
$keyname = '........';
// Copy an object.
$s3->copyObject([
    'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
    'Key'        => "{$keyname}",
    'CopySource' => "{$sourcebucket}/{$keyname}",
]);
$s3->putObjectAcl(array(
    'Bucket'    => $targetBucket,
    'Key'       => $keyname,
    'ACL'       => 'public-read'
));
```

I posted here, may be it will help other's. As i was tired for solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the other way of doing what you've got as your own response, is to create a pre-signed request [as described in the AWS documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html)

This then means that you can do something like this without having to bother with copying the object to another bucket (and also means you don't have to worry about cleaning up the unsecured bucket/object afterwards) -

```
        $s3Client = new S3Client([
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'version' => 'latest'
        ]);

        $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
            'Bucket' => $mybucket,
            'Key' => $key,
        ]);
        $request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

        // Get the actual presigned-url
        $presignedUrl = (string)$request->getUri();

        header("Location: " . $presignedUrl);
        exit;
```